# Past tense of "screenshot"

Tags: tense, verbs, nouns

Present tense

> I should screenshot this.
>
> He is taking a screenshot.

Past tense?

> I screenshotted that.
>
> He took a screenshot.

I don't know if the above past tenses are correct. is screenshotted even a correct word?

Comment: I so wish the past tense was "screenshat". But sadly it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, **[screenshot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/screenshot)** is a verb, with a past tense form of "[screenshotted](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/screenshot)." It's a relatively new coinage, obviously, but it's valid.

Comment: Correct but a bit short. Short answers tend to get flagged as low quality. Could you add some supporting information? Or some other examples (eg how 'Google' has become a verb, as in Googling, Googled etc)?

Comment: @Astralbee The question is narrow. I supplied two supporting links. To be fair, the question probably should have been closed, as it can be answered by consulting a dictionary.

Answer (score -3):

A screenshot is a thing.  That makes it a noun.

Generally, you can't treat nouns as verbs.  That means there is no such thing as a past tense noun.

There are some verbs that can be treated as nouns, but they are exceptional.  Even when they are treated as nouns, they can not be conjugated to show the tense.

So you need to add a verb.  I'll suggest the verb "to take".  In many of your examples, you're already using the verb "to take".

> I should take a screenshot of this.
>
> He is taking a screenshot.

For the past tense, you use the past tense of the verb

> I took a screenshot of that.
>
> He took a screenshot.

Comment: What you say about nouns can't be verbs is obviously untrue. Try Googling it (verb) on Google (noun).

Comment: @Astralbee Please provide one verb used as a noun (gerund is fine) where the noun form is conjugated to show the past tense.  Generally when using a verb as a noun, the verb of the sentence (not the one being used as a noun) is the one being conjugated.

Comment: "Googled". That's the past tense of "Google", which is a noun (name of the company, and of their search engine) and also an accepted verb in most dictionaries.

Comment: Also the OP is not about using a verb as a noun - it is about using a noun ("a screenshot") as a verb ("screenshotted").

Comment: @Astralbee That's a noun that was used as a verb.  Google is the noun, googled is the past tense verb that came from it.  I asked for a verb used as noun, where the noun use is past tense.

Comment: As I have already mentioned, the OP is about a noun used as a verb, so you're going off-topic. But if you want an example, how about *hug*? It is a verb with a wide scope - inanimate objects can be *hugged* by something wrapped tightly around; but in the narrow scope of human affection we can use it as a noun and say "a hug".

Comment: @Astralbee I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but I still don't have my past-tense noun.  Sure verbs can be past tense, but not nouns.  So ignore where the noun comes from for a moment.  Where's a past-tense noun?  Convert a noun to a verb if you will, and you can make it any tense you want, but my statement of no past-tense nouns still seems to hold.

Comment: Sorry, I think you've fundamentally misunderstood the OP. They are already using "screenshot" as a verb in all of their examples. You have reverted to using it as a noun, which doesn't really answer the question. I am not trying to accomplish anything, I'll bid you good-day. Hey, wait... bid. That's a past tense verb and also a noun.

Comment: @Astralbee I don't see how screenshot is a verb in the sentences "He is taking a screenshot" or "He took a screenshot"; but, it is clear now that your motivation isn't concerned with details like what is being said.

Comment: Hey @EdwinBuck and Astralbee I really appreciate your efforts here. Actually I wasn't sure whether it is a verb or noun. so I showed both uses as example. My primary concern with the question was to get the use of it in a past tense "statement/sentence". Anyway I kind of read "screenshotted" somewhere and I felt a little wierd reading that... So stackexchange to the rescue...